# jquery overlay from word

Tags: jquery, overlay

I'm using an nice overlay example from [link](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html) but want jquery to respond to a click on some text and not an image. I guessing I'm on the right trail with

```
$("img[rel]").overlay();
```

I tried using div instead of img.  Is it possible just to use link to overlay and trigger it that way  How would that change $("img[rel]").overlay();

**Triggers**

```
<img src="thumbs/barcelona-pavilion.jpg" rel="#mies1"/>
<img src="thumbs/barcelona-pavilion2.jpg" rel="#mies2"/>
```

**Overlays**

```
    <!-- large image -->
    <img src="photos/barcelona-pavilion-large.jpg" />

    <!-- image details -->
    <div class="details">
        <h3>The Barcelona Pavilion</h3>

        <h4>Barcelona, Spain</h4>

        <p>The content ...</p>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- second overlay -->
<div class="simple_overlay" id="mies2">
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* the overlayed element */
.simple_overlay {

    /* must be initially hidden */
    display:none;

    /* place overlay on top of other elements */
    z-index:10000;

    /* styling */
    background-color:#333;

    width:675px;    
    min-height:200px;
    border:1px solid #666;

    /* CSS3 styling for latest browsers */
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 90px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 90px #000;  
}

/* close button positioned on upper right corner */
.simple_overlay .close {
    background-image:url(../img/overlay/close.png);
    position:absolute;
    right:-15px;
    top:-15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:35px;
    width:35px;
}

/* styling for elements inside overlay */
    .details {
        position:absolute;
        top:15px;
        right:15px;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#fff;
        width:150px;
    }

    .details h3 {
        color:#aba;
        font-size:15px;
        margin:0 0 -10px 0;
    }
```

**JS**

```
$("img[rel]").overlay();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use a class to call it, like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="thumbs/barcelona-pavilion.jpg" class="overlay">Link 1</a>
<a href="thumbs/barcelona-pavilion2.jpg" class="overlay">Link 2</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a.overlay").overlay();
```

Comment: Thank you, but the "a" tag skips the js overlay all together and opens the image on it's own, but I think your on to something. Maybe I could tryp $("span.overlay").overlay();

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use the jQuery tools overlay specifically? It has advantages and disadvantages from other lightbox style plugins, and some of them are easier to use for what you want to call it on. If you don't need the specific advantages the tools version gives you, then an alternative might be better.

Comment: Thanks Code Junkie.  I'm always open to other options.

Comment: Well, I like [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), [Yoxview](http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/), and occasionally the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). They're often harder to visually customize than jQuery tools overlay, but I find that they all work well, offer a good set of options, and work on a lot of types of elements.